# Cordova wp8.1 app crashes upon loading adaljs library

Tags: angularjs, cordova, windows-phone-8.1, ionic-framework, adal

I have developed an app which targets WP8.1, Android and iOS. While developing for Android it is smooth sailing. I can load the adalJS libraries and make them work including authenticating and authorization to AAD.
The app uses Ionic, AdalJS and AngularJS.

When I run the app for Windows phone 8.1 on the VS2015 CTP emulator it runs, until I reference the (locally downloaded in the project) adalJS files. Since the debugging support on VS2015 for WP emulator is non-existent, I do not have an error. But I found out that when I comment out the javascript for adaljs and also the injection in the app.module and app.config it will load up the page and works.
`<head>` of the index.html:

```
<!-- IF using Sass (run gulp sass first), then uncomment below and remove the CSS includes above
<link href="css/ionic.app.css" rel="stylesheet">
-->

<script src="scripts/platformOverrides.js"></script>

<!-- ionic/angularjs js -->
<script src="assets/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>

<!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
<script src="cordova.js"></script>

<script src="assets/lib/adaljs/adal-angular.js"></script>
<script src="assets/lib/adaljs/adal.js"></script>

<!-- your app's js -->
<script src="app/app.module.js"></script>
<script src="app/app.route.js"></script>
```

app.route.js

```
angular.module('App')
    .config(['$compileProvider', '$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', '$httpProvider', 'adalAuthenticationServiceProvider',
    function ($compileProvider, $stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $httpProvider, adalProvider) { //logic here}]);
```

app.module.js:

```
angular.module('App', ['ionic','AdalAngular'])

.run(function ($ionicPlatform) {
    $ionicPlatform.ready(function () {
        // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
        // for form inputs)
        if (window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
            cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
        }
        if (window.StatusBar) {
            // org.apache.cordova.statusbar required
            StatusBar.styleDefault();
        }
    });
});
```

So I debugged it by deleting the references to the adal library and commenting out the adaljs script references in index.html, when I do the app launches and works.

I've tried to search for this error and found this:
[Mike Jone's blog post for cordova on windows phone](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/msdn_answers/archive/2015/02/10/running-cordova-apps-on-windows-and-windows-phone-8-1-using-ionic-angularjs-and-other-frameworks.aspx)
[Villa Rantala's blog post](http://blog.vjrantal.net/2015/01/08/experiences-with-ionic-on-windows-phone-8-1/)
[Old phonegap bug which is resolved](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-4873)

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

It was a VS2015 CTP5 issue.
After installing CTP6 the issue was fixed.